# One to Many Core Data binding issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have 2 Core Data objects. `Items` and `TimeLog`. The items object has a one to many relation with TimeLog and I am using the IB and Array Controller to automatically populate the 2 `NSTableView`'s

[image]

The top table view is for the items. When you select an item the bottom table should populate with the time logs.

However when I add an item, the application crashes with an error

```
<_NSFaultingMutableSet 0x102e0e790> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: date
```

I am using an Array Controller to populate all the information automatically. When I create and add and item I am not setting anything for the timeLog relationship because there is no time to add when they first add the item. The object is saving as I have logging that is triggered after the core data save event.

**Items.h**

```
@class TimeLog;

@interface Items : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *timeLog;
@end

@interface Items (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addTimeLogObject:(TimeLog *)value;
- (void)removeTimeLogObject:(TimeLog *)value;
- (void)addTimeLog:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeTimeLog:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

**TimeLog.h**

```
@class Items;

@interface TimeLog : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * time;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Items *item;

@end
```

**What is causing this error and how do I get rid of it?**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by creating another `NSArrayController` for my `TimeLog` and setting up the table like so.

**TimeLog Arra Controller**

- Set Controller Content -> Content Set -> Bind to `Items` array controller. Model Key path to `timeLog`
  [image]

Then each column of the table.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Just starting out with OS X and this has stopped my head hurting any more than it has to.  I had used ContentArray rather than ContentSet for the binding and, despite the fact that I noticed the other option, completely forgot to try that when it started crashing... until I read this.